# Is there an "include once" feature for ASP.net razor?

Tags: php, asp.net, razor

in php there's `include_once`. I'd like to be able to do the same thing with asp.net's `@Html.Partial`. Is there built-in functionality to do this?

Comment: Just call `Html.Partial`... once.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such functionality in ASP.NET but you can write your own:

```
public static class HtmlPartialHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PartialOnce(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName)
    {
        if (!htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains(partialViewName))
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(partialViewName, ""); //any value is good...
            return htmlHelper.Partial(partialViewName);
        }

        return null; //May be string.Empty is better
    }

    public static bool RenderPartialOnce(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName)
    {
        if (!htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains(partialViewName))
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(partialViewName, "");
            htmlHelper.RenderPartial(partialViewName);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not a PHP expert but I hope got the return values right...